# PostPersist is invoking but not saving

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an entity that creates a hash based on a numeric ID and salt with the **PostPersist** lifecycle hook.

I have verified the `setHash` method is being triggered and assigning a proper string (via logging) however the `hash` column is empty in the db.

What could be preventing the value from saving?

```
/**
 * Deployment
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="deployments")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\DeploymentRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Deployment

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=16, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $hash;

    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist
     */
    public function setHash()
    {
        $hashids = new Hashids($this->hashSalt, 5, 'abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz');
        $this->hash = $hashids->encode($this->getId());
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: what i remember from the post persist, you needs to flush again

Comment: That was it. It was the last item in my fixtures, so all other entities that I use that hash model on were working because I flush after each section. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From [Doctrine documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#postupdate-postremove-postpersist) :

> **postUpdate, postRemove, postPersist**
> The three post events are called inside EntityManager#flush(). Changes in here  are not relevant to the persistence in the database, but you can use these events to alter non-persistable items, like non-mapped fields, logging or even associated classes that are not directly mapped by Doctrine.

Meaning your changes on the entity will not be saved between perist() and flush()

What you could do if you really need an event, you could try a postFlushEvent where you check if the hash is null, and if so set it and flush again, but beware of endless loop (make sure you re-flush only if hash is null).

But the event will trigger everytime your entityManager flush, for updates also. My advice is if you persist in only one place of your code, just do it manually. If there are several places where the entity can be persisted, go for the event.